# No Funciona la propiedad Sticky en la Navbar

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Llevo tiempo intentando resolver porqué la propiedad sticky para la navbar no me funciona y no he podido lograr nada. Cuando comencé a hacer el código si funcionaba, pero ahora que he añadido más código no me funciona. Espero puedan ayudarme, soy principiante en html5 y css3.

Éste es el código del archivo HTML. La parte del body la divido en tres columnas, las dos de los lados son de igual tamaño, y la columna central es la más grande.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Aqui va la descripcion del sitio">
  <meta name="keywords" content="circuits, electrical circuits, electricity">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Electrical Circuits</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="img\icon.png">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Electrical Circuits</h1>
  </header>

  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#what">What is a Circuit?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#types">Types of Electrical Circuits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Electronic VS Electric Circuit</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Electrical Circuit Analysis</a></li>
  </ul>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column side">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Side</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="column middle">
    <div class="card" id="what">
      <img class="image1" src="img/image.jpg">
      <h2>What is a Circuit?</h2>
      <p>Our daily life is surrounded by electrical circuits, these are present in homes, businesses and even in cell phones. <br><br>First, let's define the word circuit. A circuit is defined as a complete and closed path around which an electric current can circulate. It can also mean a system of electrical conductors and components that form such a path. Every time you flip a switch (in operation), you are completing a circuit and letting the electrical currents do their thing.</p>
    </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="column side">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Side</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Éste es el código de mi archivo CSS. No se si habrá afectado de alguna manera el que tenga tres columnas en el body, o el estilo que le di a las imágenes.

````
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background: #D0D3D4;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
}

header{
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #00003D;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 100px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

h1{
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #1F618D;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #154360;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  text-align:justify;
}

/* Left and right column */
.column.side {
  width: 19%;
}

/* Middle column */
.column.middle {
  width: 60%;
  margin-left: 13px;
  margin-right: 13px;
}


/* Add a card effect for articles */
.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.image1{
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 20%;
  /*height: 200px;*/
}

.image2{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 50%;
}

.icon{
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .topnav a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the three columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column.side, .column.middle {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 33.33%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #00003D;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de horas intentando resolver el problema, acabo de encontrar la solución. Faltaba el siguiente código en el archivo styles.css:

```
.row:after {
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
```

Saludos. Comparto la solución por si alguien algún día la llegara a necesitar.